# How do i change this code from using 5 constants to an average of them?

Tags: excel, vba

Ive got some code which used 5 different constants (FC) i would like to instead use an average of them which i could work out in a cell on excel.

If there is any other glaring mistakes or improvements which could be made, they would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim rainfall(), evaporation(), obs_q(), FC() As Double
Dim available_w(), overflow(), interflow() As Double
Dim ccrain, ccevaporation, i, j  As Integer


'amount of data
Do
     m = Worksheets("Hydrological_Data").Cells(6 + n, 2)
    If m <> "" Then
        n = n + 1
    Else
Exit Do
    End If
Loop


ReDim rainfall(n + 1), evaporation(n + 1), obs_q(n + 1) As Double
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        obs_q(i) = Worksheets("Hydrological_Data").Cells(6 + i, 3)
        rainfall(i) = Worksheets("Hydrological_Data").Cells(6 + i, 4) * (1 + ccrain / 100)
        evaporation(i) = Worksheets("Hydrological_Data").Cells(6 + i, 5) * (1 + ccevaporation / 100)
    Next i
'initial conditions


ReDim available_w(n - 1, 5), overflow(n - 1, 5), interflow(n - 1, 5) As Double

available_w(0, 1) = FC(1) + rainfall(0) - evaporation(0)
available_w(0, 2) = FC(2) + rainfall(0) - evaporation(0)
available_w(0, 3) = FC(3) + rainfall(0) - evaporation(0)
available_w(0, 4) = FC(4) + rainfall(0) - evaporation(0)
available_w(0, 5) = FC(5) + rainfall(0) - evaporation(0)



For j = 1 To 5
    If available_w(0, j) > FC(j) Then
        overflow(0, j) = available_w(0, j) - FC(j)
        available_w(0, j) = FC(j)
    Else
        overflow(0, j) = 0
    End If

    If available_w(0, j) > 0 Then
        interflow(0, j) = available_w(0, j) * a
    Else
        interflow(0, j) = 0
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more coding advice...

Please don't use `exit` (or goto's for that matter). It's a bad practice. Also I suggest you reference your workbook as well and not just the worksheet.

You could do something like the following, for example:

```
Dim n As Long
n = 0 'as already suggested in another post, n needs to be initialized with whatever value you see fit
Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hydrological_Data").Cells(6 + n, 2) <> ""
    n = n + 1
Loop
```

Now as far as the average of FC(1)...FC(5) is concerned, I'm probably not getting where your problem is, because it's fairly easy compared to the code you've already written so far...

In any case, here's the obvious way to do it:

```
Dim FCsum As Double
Dim FCaverage As Double
Dim i As Integer
FCsum = 0
For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
    FCsum = FCsum + FC(i)
Next i
FCaverage = FCsum / 5
```

Now, if you have calculated this average in a cell using just the `AVERAGE` formula, then it's even easier. You will just use a reference to this cell like so:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hydrological_Data").Range("A1").value 'or whichever cell your average is being calculated in
```

and then use it in whatever calculation you want to perform.

Comment: Thanks @StavrosJon and Perry for your advice it is appreciated. You are right jon i did not explain my problem well.  I assumed if i wanted to use only one vale  i would do this but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: I have just worked out how to do it with one average constant, your help was much appreciated @Stavros

Comment: @JoshAlton Glad I could help. If my post really answered your question, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First, some coding advice. The Dim statements with AS at the ends only declares the last variable AS the stated type. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement

Second, n is used without initialization. It is good from to initialize variables instead of using the initialization from the compiler. This will work in most cases but if for some reason the code is re-entered or re-used it will have the wrong n to start.

I ran into this recently when creating code and testing using the debugger. I hop around in the debugger and sometimes the loops don't run because I did not initialize the loop variable.